# How to use filter() with push() in the same function

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to know if there would be a way to use the filter with the push in the same function, I tried here, but it didn't work

here is an example of the code

```
          this.storeS.getItensByCateg(paramId).subscribe((resB: any) => {
        scrollTo(0, 300);
        this.slicedItems = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
          if (resB[i]) {
            this.slicedItems.push(resB[i]);
          }
            console.log(this.slicedItems.filter(item => item.status==='I'))
          }
```

In console.log the filter works normally, but in `push(resB[i])` it doesn't work

the desired exit

```
estoque: null fotos: (6) ['8407.0', null, null, null, null, null] id: 8407 item_linkWeb: {id: 719, emp_id: 1, item_id: 8407, linkWeb_id: 693, updated_at: null, …} status: "I" tabela: {itemTabela_id: 4, item_id: 8407, vVenda: 212.9, vPromo: null, vPromoData: null}
```

But the output could also come with the status :"A", so I need the filter `status==='I'`

```
estoque: null fotos: (6) ['8407.0', null, null, null, null, null] id: 8407 item_linkWeb: {id: 719, emp_id: 1, item_id: 8407, linkWeb_id: 693, updated_at: null, …} status: "A" tabela: {itemTabela_id: 4, item_id: 8407, vVenda: 212.9, vPromo: null, vPromoData: null}
```

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to achieve. What's the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: Seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain your goal, rather than asking for seomthing like this !

Comment: I edited the question, can you check if it's clearer?

Comment: you need to filter the array on every single iteration? can you filter it outside the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because filter returns an array, not mutates the original.

That's why console log shows you, but it doesn't update.

You need

```
this.slicedItems = this.slicedItems.filter(item => item.status==='I')
```

Comment: The push being made before the filter, the console log would show whatever he is trying to do.

Comment: No worries mate, ive made that mistake before and spotted it immediately. Good luck with your project! @Leonardo